# How do I load a Ressource Path in multi-projects in proper project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-classpath

I have to use this project configuration:

```
Project 1
+ src
+ Model
  + Datamodel.dtd
Project 2
+ src
```

Project 1 does some work with xml and should load the dtd from the folder "Model". I put this folder in the classpath of project 1.
Project 1 is in the classpath of project 2.
In project 2, I call a class from project 1 which try to load "Datamodel.dtd". However, the path of my ressources points to the basepath of project 1 and not to project 2. Therefore it throws a "FileNotFoundException".

Any Ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only **exported** classpath entries **are visible** in dependent projects:

1. Select *project 1*
2. Go to ***Project > Properties*** tab ***Order and Export***
3. **Check the checkbox** of the *Model* classpath entry

Comment: The_Model_ classpath is already exported. The path of the exception still points to the directory of project 2. Well, I guess I have to use a classloader to load this ressource, right? Is there a way to retrieve a path of this ressource for accessing it with the filesystem?

Comment: @MrPotato You didn't mentioned that it is already exported. Resources on the classpath have to be read as `InputStream` (e.g. via `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)`), not as `File`. Please show your code.

Comment: I didn't know the feature before. So there is the problem. I used `File` and tried to read it and not `InputStream` with the ClassLoader. Now, it works well. Thanks.